# Is DAX from Power BI same as LOD in Tableau

Tags: powerbi, dax, tableau-api

I'm new to tableau. my question is, is DAX from Power BI same as LOD in Tableau?
It'd be great if someone could help me with an explanation for this.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are similarities for sure. In Excel it can be a way to display a value that is unaffected by filtering.

LODs are similar in that you can fix your value.

For example, if I want to know the total sales in a workbook regardless of what row/column the value is on, I could use a FIXED LOD expression:

```
{FIXED : SUM([Sales]}
```

If you put the above on Label and a Month dimension on rows, it will ignore the segmentation of months and display the total sum of sales for the entire workbook.

You can choose to fix on a different level of detail to achieve a different result:

```
{FIXED [Month] : SUM([Sales]}
```

If you put the above on Label and a month and date dimension on rows it will display the total sum of sales for each month, and ignore the date. And so on...

They're somewhat tricky to get used to, but they come up a lot in more complex workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

I would put it this way, the DAX language is at least as powerful as Tableau expressions (involving LOD or otherwise). That is, if you can do it with Tableau LOD, then there's also a way to write something equivalent with DAX.